# xfbml.ready Event in `file://` protocol

Tags: facebook, cordova

Is there a way to use the Facebook's Video Embed `xfbml.ready` in a `file://` protocol?

I haven't been able to use this code using that protocol, and I need to see if that is possible, since I'm developing a PhoneGap and currently is not working for me.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId  : '{APP-KEY}',
    xfbml  : true
  });
  FB.init(config);

  FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function (msg) {
     console.log('READY');
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: Don't think that is possible. This uses cross-domain communication via postmessage in the background, and that does not work with the file protocol for security reasons. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5466376/1427878

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for your comment. You are right